# Map domain to web application hosted in IIS

Tags: web, iis, hosting, iis-10

I have a domain purchased from Godaddy and I have published an web application in IIS 10. The site is accessible from both public IP(http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:81) and domain name(http://websitename.com:81) with port with out any problem. But I don't want to use my site with port number, If I type my domain name like http://websitename.com it should resolve to http://websitename.com:81

Can some one help me with settings or changes that I need to do on IIS and hosting provider side

Comment: If you host on port 80, then the port number can be ignored in URLs. Basic rules of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to set the port number to 80 in your iis site binding instead of the 81 port. After installing IIS on any Windows machine, by default IIS Server listens on port 80.

below is the example:

[image]